# crash when added one pointer to multiple boost::ptr_vector list

Tags: c++, boost

this the code I am testinng with: uncomment //list2.push_back(test); will crash,what's the problem? thanks
//try the list

```
boost::ptr_vector<char> list1;
boost::ptr_vector<char> list2;

char* test = new char[512];

strcpy(test,"what");

list1.push_back(test);
//list2.push_back(test);

boost::ptr_vector<char>::iterator itr;
boost::ptr_vector<char>::iterator itrDelete;

for(itr = list1.begin();itr!=list1.end();++itr)
{
    if(strcmp("what",&(*itr)) == 0 ) {
        itrDelete = itr;
    }
}
list1.erase(itrDelete);
```

In this case list2 is a small set of list1 that I keep to track for other use,but when I delete from list1 it crashes and vice versa.

Comment: Why are you using `char*` instead of C++ in a very C++ code. Why isthe tag `C`?

Comment: `boost::ptr_vector<char>` is a vector of pointers, each pointer pointing to **one** character. These pointers **own** their content (will delete it when the vector is destroyed, etc). It is totally inappropriate for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the actual erasing of the element that's causing the crash, but the other container from which you have not erased the element going out of scope.

All [Boost Pointer Containers](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) expect the objects you add to them to be dynamically allocated, and will call `delete` on the object when you remove it from the container.

In your example, you've added the same dynamically allocated object to both containers, so both will expect to have ownership of that `char` array. When you call

```
list1.erase(itrDelete);
```

`list1` will `delete` the `char` array. Later, when `list2` goes out of scope, it too will attempt to `delete` all elements you've added to it, which results in double deletion of the `char` array pointed to by `test`, which is undefined behavior.

If you want to share the same dynamically allocated object between two vectors, you should use

```
boost::ptr_vector<char> list1;
std::vector<char *> list2;
```

Now, `list1` has ownership of the dynamically allocated `char` arrays you add to both, `list2` will simply serve as an accessor to the same array.